# What is the colour of chromium(III) chloride solution?

Tags: aqueous-solution, ionic-compounds, color

I had a question asking about the colour of the solution of chromium(III) chloride in my exam, all my colleagues have different answers, I couldn't find any exact answer after searching!

Comment: Related: [How hydrate isomerism results difference in colours?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/28006/7951)

Comment: It depends on the amount of time since the solution has been created, the temperature, and possibly present excess chloride ions.

Comment: wikipedia says it it dark green when exist as hydrate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The color of the solution may vary as long it is not in equilibrium.

According Bjerrum and Bjerrum<sup>1</sup> a $\ce{1\mathrm{M}}$ chromium (III) chloride solution in equilibrium at 25° C contains about 13% monochloro and 85% hexaqua ions.

The absorption spectrum published shows minima at $\ce{480 \mathrm{nm}}$ (blue) for the hexaqua and $\ce{510 \mathrm{nm}}$ (green) for the monochloro complex.

[image: absorption minimum colors]

When we integrate over the spectrum we get the following colors.

[image: colors integrated over the whole spectrum]

However, it should be noted that the colors vary with spectral optical depth (concentration, thickness of the medium).

<sub>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9wIJ.png) Bjerrum, M.J. and Bjerrum, J., 1990. Estimation of Small Stability Constants in Aqueous Solutions. The Chromium(III) Chloride System. Acta Chem. Scand. 44: 358-363.</sub>